# Selenium 'send_keys' does not work for YouTube

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, youtube

I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to create my first automatization test where OS is gonna open Chrome browser, opens YouTube and enteres a word in the search bar.
Well, browser opens, YouTube opens, but OS doesn't enter any word.
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/mariabiriulina/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://youtube.com/')
searchbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.click()
searchbox.send_keys('Selenium')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there could be 2 element in the page with the same id as `search`, we need to get the `input` element having id `search`.

The below code, with the changes should work fine now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/mariabiriulina/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://youtube.com/')
searchbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="search"]')
searchbox.click()
searchbox.send_keys('Selenium')
```

Comment: Xpath is not unique? I checked with inspect and there is only 1 id="search-input"

Comment: Then I m not really sure, why it's fetching some other id `search` and not this one.